# Drawing a simple line in a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Is there a way to add a simple line through a UILabel. I have a 40px high UILabel and simply want to draw a black line horizontally through the middle (at 20px). Is there a way to do this without having to create an image and setting it as the background?

Comment: Yes you can draw line by keeping height lesser or otherwise you can make an image & you can use.

Comment: It your label is going to have some text there

Comment: if label consist text then you can use strike through with attributed string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are couple of ways. For example, you can add 1-point height subview to the label:

Swift 3.0 update:

```
    let lineView = UIView(
        frame: CGRect(x: 0, 
            y: label.bounds.size.height / 2,
            width: label.bounds.size.width,
            height: 1
        )
    )
    lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    label.addSubview(lineView)
```

Answer (score 5):

if your label consist text then you can use strike through in label like this.

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *newStringStrike = @"your text";
NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newStringStrike];
[attributeString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
                        value:@1
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])];

labelName.attributedText = attributeString;
```

Comment: Working perfectly fine. but instead of "NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName" i want "NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to subclass `UILabel` and overwrite the `drawRect` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using UILabel

> height=1 width=as you need

and make its background colour as black and put it on your 40px UILabel.  Hope this gonna help you.

Answer (score 1):

[@Anil solanki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34176207/1107226) using Swift 3.1:

```
let newStringStrike = "your text"
let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newStringStrike)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

labelName.attributedText = attributedString
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift4:

```
 let newStringStrike = "your text"
    let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newStringStrike)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))

    yourLabel = attributeString
```

Answer (score 0):

simply create an NSAttributedString and assign to your label

```
    let newStringStrike = "your text"
    let attributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newStringStrike)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    yourLabel.attributedText = attributeString
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous answers you can define something like this for swift 5

```
extension UILabel{
func setTextWithStrike(text: String)
{
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    self.attributedText = attributedString

}
```

}

and then use it like this:

```
labelWithStike.setTextWithStrike(text: "text with strike")
```